# Check if set of characters exists in a string or not - Improvement

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Two English words are similar if they only contain the same alphabetical letters. For example, food and good are not similar, but dog and good are similar. (If A is similar to B, then all letters in A are contained in B, and all letters in B are contained in A.)

Given a word W and a list of words L, find all words in L similar to W. Print the word count to standard output.

**Example:**

**Input (stdin):**

```
love
velo low vole lovee volvell lowly lower lover levo loved love lovee lowe lowes lovey lowan lowa evolve loves volvelle lowed love
```

**Output (stdout):**

`14`

**Explanation:**

The words in L similar to love are
`velo vole lovee volvell lover  levo loved love lovee lovey evolve loves volvelle love`

which count up to `14`.

So my current solution is like below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{"velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
            "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"};
    String s = "love";
    int result = 0;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(buildPattern(s));

    for (String val : arr) {
        if (p.matcher(val).find()) result++;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}

private static String buildPattern(String s) {
    String pattern = "^";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        pattern += "(?=.*" + s.charAt(i) + ")";
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

And I'm wondering if there is any improvement to my simple code.

Is Aho-Corasick applicable solution?

Comment: Check out codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can easily verify manually that only 10 words match, not 14.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt wow, I'm trying to see that really, It's not obvious for me, I counted 14 every time.

Comment: "velo" 1 , "low" , "vole" 2, "lovee" 3 , "volvell" 4 , "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo" 5 , "loved", "love" 6,
            "lovee" 7 , "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve" 8, "loves", "volvelle" 9, "lowed", "love" 10

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt why you didn't count (love)r, (love)d, (love)y and (love)s?

Comment: "If A is similar to B, then **all** letters in A are contained in B, and **all** letters in B are contained in A.". Since "r", "d", "y" and "s" are not in "love", these words are not similar to "love".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt wow, thanks, it's more clear for me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are only 26 letters, and there are 32 bits in an `int`, an `int` is big enough to hold all the information about which letters appear in a word:

```
static int getFingerprint(String s)
{
    int result=0;
    for (int i = s.length()-1; i>=0; --i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c>='a' && c<='z')
            result |= 1<<(int)(c-'a');
        else if (c>='A' && c<='Z')
            result |= 1<<(int)(c-'A');
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{"velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
        "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"};
    String s = "love";

    int fingerprint = getFingerprint(s);

    int matches = 0;
    for (String item : arr) {
        if (getFingerprint(item)==fingerprint)
            ++matches;
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simplify the regex, there is no need for the lookahead, simple "^[love]*$" should do the trick.

```
private static String buildPattern(String s) {
    String pattern = "^[";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        pattern += s.charAt(i);
    }
    pattern += "]*$";
    return pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using regex for this and would check the letters myself.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String[] arr = new String[]{"velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
          "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"};
  String s = "love";
  int result = 0;

  for (String word : arr)
  {
    if (isSimilar(s, word))
    {
      result++;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(result);
}

private static boolean isSimilar(String word, String test)
{
  for (char c : test.toCharArray())
  {
    if (word.indexOf(c) == -1)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Although currently my example above is only returning `10`?

Comment: Well, I think there is not much difference because the `indexOf` is **O(nm)**

Comment: I would personally argue that this is cleaner to read though as it's much easier to see what the code is doing. Regex expressions can be hard to interpret, let alone ones which are generated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I only count 10 which should succeed, both with my implementation and when I manually checked.

It is as simple as comparing whether the set of letters in each word is equal

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    String word = "love";
    List<String> strs = Arrays.asList(
        "velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
        "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"
    );

    System.out.println(
        strs.stream()
           .filter(str -> chars(word).equals(chars(str)))
           .count()
    );
}

private static Set<Character> chars(String word)
{
    return word.chars()
        .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: You also getting 10 makes me feel better about my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{"velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
            "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"};
    String s = "love";

    Set<Character> searchWordCharacters = getDistinctCharacters(s);
    long result = Stream.of(arr)
            .map(Scratch::getDistinctCharacters)
            .filter(wordCharacters -> wordCharacters.size() == searchWordCharacters.size())
            .filter(wordCharacters -> wordCharacters.containsAll(searchWordCharacters))
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .count();
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static Set<Character> getDistinctCharacters(String word) {
    return word.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Result: 10

Comment: matched words are :{"velo", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "levo", "love",
                "lovee", "evolve", "volvelle", "love"}

Answer (score 0):

count 10 which should succeed !

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "velo", "low", "vole", "lovee",
        "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
        "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve",
        "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love" };

String s = "love";

Predicate<Character> p = x -> s.indexOf(x) > -1 ? true : false;

List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(arr);

asList.stream().forEach(x -> {
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        chars.add(x.charAt(i));
    }
    boolean anyMatch = chars.stream().allMatch(p);
    if (anyMatch)
        count++;
});

System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[]{"velo", "low", "vole", "lovee", "volvell", "lowly", "lower", "lover", "levo", "loved", "love",
                "lovee", "lowe", "lowes", "lovey", "lowan", "lowa", "evolve", "loves", "volvelle", "lowed", "love"};
        String s = "love";
        int count = 0;

        boolean[] characters_state = new boolean[26];
        Arrays.fill(characters_state, false);
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            characters_state[s.charAt(i) - 'a'] = true;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (check(arr[i], characters_state.clone())) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    static boolean check(String s, boolean[] characters_state) {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(!characters_state[s.charAt(i) - 'a']) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Output

```
10

real    0m0,210s
user    0m0,206s
sys 0m0,025s
```